# Android- getChildAt(poisition) produces null

Tags: android, listview

Guys i have a Custom alert dialogue and inside that i am inflating a listView
i want to access the child of that listview but it produces error can anyone help here is my relevant code snippet

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
                        View alertView = AddExpenses.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_alert_expenses, null);

                        int amount = Integer.parseInt(etExpensesAmount.getText().toString());
                        final ListView lvAlertDialogue = (ListView) alertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_alert_expenses);
                        final TextView tvTotal = (TextView) alertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);
                        tvTotal.setText(etExpensesAmount.getText().toString());
                        CustomAdapterAlertList customAdapterAlertList = new CustomAdapterAlertList(AddExpenses.this, listSelectedContact, amount);
                        lvAlertDialogue.setAdapter(customAdapterAlertList);

                        alertDialogBuilder.setView(alertView);
                        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                        alertDialog.show();


                        final EditText etAmount;
                        View singleView = lvAlertDialogue.getChildAt(listSelectedContact.size()-1);  //singleView is null here
```

Comment: maybe you are calling getChildAt(poisition) after your alert dismiss

Comment: it produces null without showing alert dialogue

Comment: you haven't populated your list, then how you get getChild()? post your full source code

Comment: listSelectedContact does have 3 Objects in that i have checked

Comment: if i comment out the getChildAt() alert dialogue appears with 3 items

Comment: i hope there is something missing in your code.  are you using getChildAt()  at some item click ?

Comment: No i am using just like i have posted

Comment: Don't call View singleView = lvAlertDialogue.getChildAt(listSelectedContact.size()-1);  
code after the  alertDialog.show(). add some button over dialog and add this code in it.

Answer (score 0):

getChildAt() works for the visible item in list view otherwise it will return null.
Seeing your code I suppose you want the last item. You can try the following code.

```
View singleView = lvAlertDialog.getChildAt(lvAlertDialog.getLastVisiblePosition()):
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are calling `lvAlertDialog.getChildAt(lvAlertDialog.getLastVisiblePosition())`
just after the alertDialog.show();

`getChildAt` is excuteing before showing alertDialog and
getChildAt will work if and only if the dialog is visible. 
so it is null.

Try this code. Hope It will work.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
    View alertView = AddExpenses.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_alert_expenses, null);
    int amount = Integer.parseInt(etExpensesAmount.getText().toString());
    final ListView lvAlertDialogue = (ListView) alertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_alert_expenses);
    final TextView tvTotal = (TextView) alertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_amount);
    tvTotal.setText(etExpensesAmount.getText().toString());
    CustomAdapterAlertList customAdapterAlertList = new CustomAdapterAlertList(AddExpenses.this, listSelectedContact, amount);
    lvAlertDialogue.setAdapter(customAdapterAlertList);
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(alertView);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            View singleView = lvAlertDialogue.getChildAt(listSelectedContact.size() - 1);  //singleView is null here     
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
```